Confusion about direct limit of Hilbert space
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space with orthnormal basis $(e_{i})_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$, let $S:H\rightarrow H$ be the left shift operator. Consider a directed system $(H,\leq)$ with all the object is $H$, and the transition map be $S$. Consider its direct limit $H'$, for $e_{i}\in H_{j}$, the norm of $e_{i}$ is always zero, since it is equivalent to $0$ to $S^{i}(H_{j})$, and the norm of $H'$ is the quotient norm of $\oplus_{i\in\mathbb{N}}H_{i}$ modulo the equivalence relation, which takes infinmum. So all $x\in H'$ has norm zero.
Clearly something is wrong, what are the mistakes?

Nothing is wrong; you've just proven that the direct limit (I assume you're taking this in the category of Banach spaces and bounded linear maps or something) is zero.

Incidentally this also happens in the category of vector spaces; if we take $V$ to be the countable-dimensional vector space with basis $e_1, e_2, \dots $ and $S : V \to V$ to be the left shift the same direct limit in vector spaces is also zero, and for the same reason ($S$ eventually annihilates every vector).
